Regex for content disposition
What is regex for the string (content disposition) attachment;filename*=UTF-8''archive-2024-10-04T22%3A40%3A36.148226.zip and get attachment and archive-2024-10-04T22%3A40%3A36.148226.zip?
* and UTF-8'' can be and not be.
I tried this (attachment|inline);filename[*]?=[UTF\-8'']?(\S+) but it is not working.

Use non-capturing group instead of [UTF\-8'']?, i.e. (attachment|inline);filename\*?=(?:UTF\-8'')?(\S+)

@WiktorStribiżew, that works. Thanks
